# Filter on a distinct field with TastyPie

Tags: django, tastypie

Suppose I have a `Person` model that has a first name field and a last name field. There will be many people who have the same first name. I want to write a TastyPie resource that allows me to get a list of the unique first names (without duplicates).

Using the Django model directly, you can do this easily by saying something like `Person.objects.values("first_name").distinct()`. How do I achieve the same thing with TastyPie?

Comment: SO isn't letting me answer the question, but it looks like ModelResource just can't do what I need in this case, so I just created a custom resource by deriving `Resource`.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

I've adapted the apply_filters method linked below to use the values before making the `distinct` call.

```
def apply_filters(self, request, applicable_filters):
    qs = self.get_object_list(request).filter(**applicable_filters)

    values = request.GET.get('values', '').split(',')
    if values:
        qs = qs.values(*values)

    distinct = request.GET.get('distinct', False) == 'True'
    if distinct:
        qs = qs.distinct()

    return qs
```

`values` returns dictionaries instead of model objects, so I don't think you need to override `alter_list_data_to_serialize`.

**Original response**

There is a nice solution to the `distinct` part of the problem [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-tastypie/YWyeYjmhqUQ) involving a light override of `apply_filters`.

I'm surprised I'm not seeing a slick way to filter which fields are returned, but you could implement that by overriding [`alter_list_data_to_serialize`](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#alter-list-data-to-serialize) and deleting unwanted fields off the objects just before serialization.

```
def alter_list_data_to_serialize(self, request, data):
    data = super(PersonResource, self).alter_list_data_to_serialize(request, data)
    fields = request.GET.get('fields', None)
    if fields is not None:
        fields = fields.split(',')
        # Data might be a bundle here. If so, operate on data.objects instead.
        data = [
            dict((k,v) for k,v in d.items() if k in fields)
            for d in data
        ]
    return data
```

Combine those two to use something like `/api/v1/person/?distinct=True&values=first_name` to get what you're after.  That would work generally and would still work with additional filtering (`&last_name=Jones`).

Comment: This approach doesn't eliminate the duplicate names because the `distinct` operation happens first, so I get distinct `Person` objects not distinct `first_names`.